# Weblogic server getting StuckThreadMaxTime exception . How do I fix it?

Tags: java, rest, weblogic

I have a REst service exposed, which inturn calls a script files(shell script), which takes 20 mins to exceute and send response. I am getting the below exception in logs.

```
<Error> <WebLogicServer> <AdminServer>     
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self- tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1457678291528> <BEA-000337> 
<[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "606" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 606763 ms
[
POST /svc/oneclick/wsAuto/createTemplate/005056A509C4 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: oneclick
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-For: 10.19.120.25
X-Forwarded-Host: 10.19.120.48
X-Forwarded-Server: XXX-XXX-template-sa1.XXX.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
Thread-34 "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" <alive, suspended, waiting, priority=1, DAEMON> {-- Waiting for notification on: java.lang.UNIXProcess@9a5ed5a[fat lock]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becouse your processing takes 20min and default setting of StuckThreadMaxTime is set to 600 seconds, you will see such errors in logs. 
You have two options:

- make processing faster
- set StuckThreadMaxTime with bigger value (its placed on weblogic console in: domain > Environment > Servers > Admin Server > Configuration/Tuning)

Answer (score 0):

If processing really needs 20mins then change the StuckThreadMaxTime on all servers in the domain. 
Ideally on the server where Application is deployed.
How to change: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/tuning/TuningExecuteThreads.html